# Is it possible to simultaneously use both the center and bounds attributes in Leaflet.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I have an web application, written using Angular.js and angular-leaflet-directive, that displays a selection of roads on a map. I have included some bookmarks for easy navigation to certain areas and so was basing map extent navigation on using the `center` and `zoom` attributes.

I am now also including functionality to determine whether a road is visible in the current map extent, using:
`map.getBounds().contains([roadLatA, roadLngA]) || map.getBounds().contains([roadLatB, roadLngB])`, where A and B refer to the end points of a road.

This works perfectly on page load but after any sort of interaction (e.g. drag, zoom events) when `getBounds()` is called again, it returns the same LatLng for each corner of the bounding box, which are the values that are set as the default `center` coordinates. After a lot of refactoring I cannot find a way to incorporate both `center` and `getBounds()` successfully.

Is it possible or is there a limitation within either angular-leaflet-directive or leaflet.js that means the two methods of setting map extent conflict with each other?

Comment: The `getBounds` behaviour you describe is very strange. Any chance you can share more code, possibly reproducing your issue online? (e.g. on Plunker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now resolved the problem, the issue was in calling `leafletData.getMap()` without passing in the `id` of the map element.

This behaviour was throwing me as the initial `getMap()` call (without an `id`) was returning the correct map object, but on subsequent calls (after user interaction) the `$promise` was not being resolved and so I wasn't getting undefined or any other errors. I guess the `getBounds()` function was then being called on the wrong map object.